# Lifecycle of angular no more triggered after click on a marker on google maps - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm using [cordova-plugin-googlemaps (v2.1.1)](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) through [@ionic-native/google-maps (v4.4.2)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/).

I've a index of places (called EstablishmentsPage) that I show in a map or in a list. In the map I listen to the click on the markers and then I show the detailPage. On the list is just a button.

Map:

```
marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.navCtrl.push(EstablishmentPage, { establishment });
    })
```

List:

```
onClick(establishment: Establishment) {
    this.navCtrl.push(EstablishmentPage, { establishment });
}
```

Both are opening my detailPage, but with the one from the map, all the change of variables/getters are no more "binded" back to the view. (I see the logs of the method `toggleAsFavorite()` when I click on the "heart button" but it does look selected in the view).

`ngDoCheck()` and `ngOnChanges()` are no more called (all the `ngOnInit`, `ionViewDidLoad`, etc. are called as usual). I try to hide or remove the map juste before the `this.navCtrl.push(...)` or replace `push` by `setRoot`. I did also a full page with only the map and not two components. But still get this problem.

My Config:
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v6.10.3
npm   : 5.6.0 
OS    : macOS Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Comment: Please update the maps plugins to `2.2.5`

Comment: @ionic-native/google-maps is not yet fully compatible with the ^2.2.5 (on master but not yet on npm), that was my first configuration ;-) . The problem was from the ngZone like answered by @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Well, I already sent a PR to update the `@ionic-native/google-maps`, but the ionic-team focus on the capacitor project. That's why we have been just waiting, waiting, waiting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GoogleMaps code probably runs outside Angulars zone if you're not using angular-google-maps (or similar).

You can work around by forcing callbacks back into the zone

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

...

marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
.subscribe(() => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.navCtrl.push(EstablishmentPage, { establishment });
    });
})
```

then Angular is again able to recognize when it has to run change detection.

Comment: exactly! thanks a lot! Still a bit weird that all the initialization worked but not the check...

Comment: The initialization code is probably executed in code that runs inside the zone, but when your code is called from the google maps library, this code can run outside the zone. Also some other event can cause change detection that updates the view, but when there is no notification from zone and also no other event happened then Angular just does nothing.